# How to add TinyMCE editor inside the TinyMCE popup

Tags: javascript, plugins, popup, tinymce

I have one TinyMCE plugin, and I want to create dynamically new TinyMCE editors inside the popup. The problem is that I can't do that while tiny_mce_popup.js script is loaded in my popup, and that script is necessary for my plugin. Is there any workaround?

Comment: This isn't really a full answer - but I'd consider having an iframe in your popup that pointed to a page containing a new TinyMce instance. It's an iframe inside an iframe so will require some javascript magic to sort out the communication - but it should work.

Comment: That's very messy solution. You know what's weird, I manage to create new editor with "new tinymce.Editor" object and then I try to add id to the editors collection. But, when I call show() or hide() methods on the first element there (main editor), it works, but not on the new one. BTW, my code is already in the iframe, because popup content is rendered trough the iframe.

Comment: If the popup content is already in an iframe are you sure you're calling the show() / hide() methods correctly - i.e. is the code doing the calling in the same document as the TinyMCE instance and if not are you navigating the iframe hierarchy correctly?  Seems most likely that the javascript communication is a problem here.  An example would help further.